# Upgraded ag-grid from V22.1.1 to V28.2.1. In the sideBar columns tool panel check/uncheck functionality for checkbox is not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue, vue-property-decorator

I upgraded ag-grid-community, ag-grid-enterprise, ag-grid-vue from V22.1.1 to V28.2.1. I upgraded vue-property-decorator to V9.1.2 (latest). I am using vue version V2.6.10.

I have a sideBar in ag-grid which has both default columns and filters. When I click on checkbox on columns tool panel, the checkbox is getting checked, when I click on the same checkbox, the checkbox is not getting unchecked. But when I click on the text beside checkbox, It is getting checked/unchecked.

The same issue is happening with pivot mode toogle button. When I click on the pivot mode text, the toggle is working fine. But when I click on the toggle button, the toggle is not working.

In grid-options I used.  this._grid_params.config.sidebar  is true,  toolpanelList has columns and filters

```
toolpanelList.push(...['columns', 'filters']);
 sideBar:
        this._grid_params.config && this._grid_params.config.sidebar 
          ? {
            toolPanels: [...toolpanelList],
            
          }
          : false,
```

I tried upgrading the version to V29.0.0. But no luck. I want the checkbox and toggle button on the columns tool panel on sideBar for ag-grid to function properly (check/uncheck)

Comment: Please provide a *runnable* [mcve] using codesandbox.io or similar.